# Avoid page breaks in \lstlistings

Tags: floats, listings, page-breaking

I'm trying to avoid page breaks in my `lstlisting` (seen in section 0.0.2) I know I can remedy this by floating my `lstlisting`, but it adds some unwanted white space (seen in section 0.0.1).

[image: float]

Is there an alternative to `float` so that my `lstlisting` will not break across pages?

*OR*

Can I configure `float` to eliminate the white space so it looks identical to how it is when not in a `float`

[image: no float]

*I apologize for the cruft in my MWE. I'm just trying to use this in a much larger document, so I'd rather keep it as close to it as possible.

```
\documentclass{article}

% New commands
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\superscript}[1]{\ensuremath{^{\textrm{#1}}}}

% Modified commands
\renewcommand*\abstractname{Revision History}

%%%%% Packages and configuration %%%%%
\usepackage[firstpage]{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{\textsc{Confidential}}
\SetWatermarkScale{4}
\SetWatermarkColor[gray]{0.9}

%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
%\fancyfoot[LE,CO]{\thepage}           % page number in "outer" position of footer line
%\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{Message of the day} % other info in "inner" position of footer line

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{dark-red}{rgb}{0.4,0.15,0.15}
\definecolor{dark-blue}{rgb}{0.15,0.15,0.4}
\definecolor{medium-blue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{light-grey}{gray}{0.8}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}% keep at end
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={black},
    citecolor={dark-blue}, 
    urlcolor={medium-blue}
}

%\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
%\usepackage[letterpaper, top=0.7in, bottom=0.9in, left=0.7in, right=0.7in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}


%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ %
language=C,                % choose the language of the code
basicstyle=\footnotesize,       % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
%numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
%numberstyle=\footnotesize,      % the size of the fonts that are used for the line-numbers
%stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it is 1 each line will be numbered
%numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
%backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
%frame=single,           % adds a frame around the code
tabsize=4,          % sets default tabsize to 4 spaces
captionpos=b,           % sets the caption-position to bottom
breaklines=true,        % sets automatic line breaking
breakatwhitespace=false,    % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
%escapeinside={\%*}{*)}          % if you want to add a comment within your code
}

\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@afterheading}%
    {\clubpenalty \@M}{\clubpenalties 2 \@M \@M }{}{}
\patchcmd{\@afterheading}%
    {\clubpenalty \@clubpenalty}{\clubpenalties 1 \@clubpenalty }{}{}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]

\subsubsection{Lorem Ipsum Dolomite}\leavevmode
\begin{lstlisting}
void abc_defgh_ijklmn_stuff * const ( void );
\end{lstlisting}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc id sapien eget magna tempus ornare vitae ut dolor. Donec pharetra diam vitae erat sollicitudin a blandit sapien blandit. Nam ligula metus, imperdiet ut accumsan non, tincidunt id a.

\subsubsection{abcde}
\begin{lstlisting}
static boolean abcde
(
abc_defg_hijk * const   lm
);
\end{lstlisting}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc id sapien eget magna tempus ornare vitae ut dolor. Donec pharetra diam vitae erat sollicitudin a blandit sapien blandit. Nam ligula metus, imperdiet ut accumsan non, tincidunt id a.\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: 90% are 4-5 line function declarations and I have a portion of them breaking across pages. As my MWE is derived from some documentation that I'm writing, I'd like to avoid moving a bunch of `\newpage` around every time I update it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I ensure that a listing is not going to be split?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18492/how-can-i-ensure-that-a-listing-is-not-going-to-be-split)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Wrapping the `lstlisting` inside a `minipage` (of width `\linewidth`) boxes the content making it unbreakable and avoids breaking across the page boundary:

```
...
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
static boolean abcde
(
abc_defg_hijk * const   lm
);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
...
```

Depending on the location of usage, you may have to prepend the environment with `\noindent` to avoid any paragraph indentation.

A somewhat similar approach is followed if you load the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) and use

```
...
\begin{lstlisting}[float,floatplacement=H]
static boolean abcde
(
abc_defg_hijk * const   lm
);
\end{lstlisting}
...
```

More on the float placement `H` is discussed in [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)

Comment: Just a small remark, shouldn't we use also `\begin{center}`. Otherwise I get my text and my listing intertwined.

Comment: @AlexanderCska: Not really.

Comment: According to the current docs of the ``listing`` package its:
``\begin{lstlisting}[float=H]``

Comment: Is there a way to redefine a command such that you can do something like `\begin{code} \end{code}` instead of copy pasting both the minipage and the lstlisting everytime?

Comment: @Winter: Yes. You can define your own/custom listing environment using `\lstnewenvironment`. See [How can I define a custom `listing` environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78992/5764)

Comment: You probably want to use `\noindent` before your minipage.

Answer (score 18):

I'm using version 1.5 (2013) of the `listings` package. I use `lstinputlisting` to include the code from the file, and I just put `float` inside the options of the environment. It works fine.

For example, this goes in my preamble:

```
\lstdefinestyle{freefempp}{
  language=C++,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{violet},
  identifierstyle=\color{blue},
  morekeywords={ border, buildmesh, cos, dx, dy, fespace, fill, func,
    int2d, label, mesh, on, pi, plot, problem, sin, real, x, y},
  % float,
  frame=single,
  numbers=left
}

\lstset{style=freefempp}
```

And this goes in my document's body.

```
\lstinputlisting
  [caption=Solution to question 1, float, linerange={1-21}, firstnumber=1]
  {listings/ex1-1.edp}
```

However, the float option only works inside the `lstinputlisting` environment definition, not inside the style definition. Maybe this bug will be corrected in future versions.

Comment: +1 This is the solution that worked for me. With this, I don't have to deal with extra indentation that comes with minipage.

Answer (score 6):

I use a similar solution to the one proposed by werner.
However I prefer to define the minipage with text instead of line width:

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.95\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}

\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
```

"c" for centering and "0.95\textwidth" to make the listing a little bit smaller than the rest of the text.

Comment: Why do you prefer `\textwidth` when `\linewidth` adjusts with you margins? For example, when you set an `lstlisting` inside a list. Also, why not a full `\textwidth`?

Comment: I work with two-column styles most of the time. 
In such styles, \textwidth is typically the better choice as listings rarely fit into a single column.
However, in one-column styles it makes no difference. 
So \textwidth is valid for both of these styles.