# How can I define a custom listing environment?

Tags: listings, environments

I am trying to define an enviroment for a specific programming language, F#. Here's my code:

```
\definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{turqusnumbers}{rgb}{0.17,0.57,0.69}
\definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}

\lstdefinelanguage{FSharp}
    {morekeywords={let, new, match, with, rec, open, module, namespace, type, of, member, and, for, in, do, begin, end, fun, function, try, mutable, if, then, else},
    keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
    sensitive=false,
    morecomment=[l][\color{greencomments}]{///},
    morecomment=[l][\color{greencomments}]{//},
    morecomment=[s][\color{greencomments}]{{(*}{*)}},
    morestring=[b]",
    stringstyle=\color{redstrings}
    }

\newenvironment{fslisting}
  {
    \lstset{
        language=FSharp,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        breaklines=true,
        columns=fullflexible}
    \begin{lstlisting}
  }
  {
    \end{lstlisting}
  }
```

Then I'm trying to use it as such:

```
\begin{fslisting}
type 'a Process = 'a Signal IObservable
\end{fslisting}
```

But it doesn't work. The output log says that the listing is not terminated - or is terminated by the document. So the rest of the document is also formatted as a listing, which is of course not the intention.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot create a new `lstlisting` environment via `\newenvironment`. You need to use `\lstnewenvironment`. See the [`listings`](//ctan.org/pkg/listings) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/listings), section **4.5 Environments** (p 42).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{turqusnumbers}{rgb}{0.17,0.57,0.69}
\definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}

\lstdefinelanguage{FSharp}
    {morekeywords={let, new, match, with, rec, open, module, namespace, type, of, member, and, for, in, do, begin, end, fun, function, try, mutable, if, then, else},
    keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
    sensitive=false,
    morecomment=[l][\color{greencomments}]{///},
    morecomment=[l][\color{greencomments}]{//},
    morecomment=[s][\color{greencomments}]{{(*}{*)}},
    morestring=[b]",
    stringstyle=\color{redstrings}
    }

\lstnewenvironment{fslisting}
  {
    \lstset{
        language=FSharp,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        breaklines=true,
        columns=fullflexible}
  }
  {
  }
\begin{document}

\begin{fslisting}
type 'a Process = 'a Signal IObservable
\end{fslisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The section in the reference changed to 5.14 on page 42

Answer (score 11):

Just use the provided `\lstnewenvironment` command.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{turqusnumbers}{rgb}{0.17,0.57,0.69}
\definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}

\lstdefinelanguage{FSharp}
    {morekeywords={let, new, match, with, rec, open, module, namespace, type, of, member, and, for, in, do, begin, end, fun, function, try, mutable, if, then, else},
    keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
    sensitive=false,
    morecomment=[l][\color{greencomments}]{///},
    morecomment=[l][\color{greencomments}]{//},
    morecomment=[s][\color{greencomments}]{{(*}{*)}},
    morestring=[b]",
    stringstyle=\color{redstrings}
    }

\lstnewenvironment{fslisting}
    {\lstset{language=FSharp,
                basicstyle=\ttfamily,
                breaklines=true,
                columns=fullflexible
    }}
    {}

\begin{document}

\begin{fslisting}
type 'a Process = 'a Signal IObservable
\end{fslisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: and again too late... ;)