# Create user defined command

Tags: macros, pdftex

I am new to Latex, I need to create a user defined command or Macro.
I need to print unix shell commands on a pdf, the code looks like below

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
$sudo apt-get install build-essential
\end{lstlisting}
```

This has to be done for every unix command and I have lot too many of them. For this reason I thought I can create a new command called `\shell` like this

```
\newcommand{\shell}[1]{
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
#1
\end{lstlisting}
}
```

I am getting some `!Emergency stop` errors. can someone tell me what am I doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I define a custom listing environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78992/how-can-i-define-a-custom-listing-environment)

Comment: `lstlisting` are very fragile constructs - do not try to build your own commands around them if you do not really need them. But if you want to save the work of typing `[language=bash]` every time, there are other ways.

Comment: could you please tell me the other ways?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78995/36296, sounds like `\lstnewenvironment` might be of use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this command and you will not receive that emergency stop error:

```
\newcommand{\shell}[1]{\lstinline[language=bash] {#1} }
```

I am not sure about correctness of using `newcommand` while, in fact, you are defining `newenvironment`. 
If you are interested in defining a new environment, you can use the syntax addressed here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_environments

Comment: Even better, `\newcommand{\shell}{\lstinline[language=bash]}`

Answer (score 4):

As stated in comments, I would dissuade from trying to wrap `lstlisting` into custom environments. They are really fragile and do behave different from "normal" tex commands. But `listings` itself provides the ability to define own `lstnewenvironment` which saves you from typing `[language=bash]` every time.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{shell}{\lstset{language=bash}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{shell}
$sudo apt-get install build-essential
\end{shell}

\end{document}
```