# Create an environment that uses another environment

Tags: environments

I am trying to create an environment that wraps another one, `lstlisting` here.

```
\documentclass[12pt, dvipsnames]{report}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\newenvironment{code}[1]{\begin{lstlisting}#1}{\end{lstlisting}}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}
some code
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

When I compile this code with texmaker, there is an "Emergency Stop", because "no legal \end" was found. I guess that the parser gets stuck in an infinite loop.

How to fix this code?

EDIT: replacing `newenvironment` by `lstnewenvironment` leads to the error "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup" at the line `\end{code}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, dvipsnames]{report}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{code}[1]{\begin{lstlisting}#1}{\end{lstlisting}}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}
some code
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

Comment: does it helps? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78992/how-can-i-define-a-custom-listing-environment

Comment: I tried to replace `newenvironment` by `lstnewenvironment` but it leads to the error `Missing \endcsname inserted.` on the line `\begin{code}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for posting a minimal document with your question. Since it seems that your question is a duplicate, please edit your code to show the `lstnewenvironment` code that didn't work, since there is probably a simple error there.

Comment: @AlanMunn: done

Comment: Try `\lstnewenvironment{code}[1]{#1}{}` and then use: `\begin{code}{\lstset{language={TeX},basicstyle=\ttfamily, breaklines=true}}` but it would be better to not use parameters at all and have the `\lstset` command in the place of `#1`

Comment: @koleygr: I can't see how it helps, could you give a complete example? Using `\lstset` instead of `#1` is not an option though, since I want to create an environment that needs nothing more than the code.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that this question should be marked as a duplicate since the other question proposes to use `lstnewenvironment` which doesn't work in my situation.

Comment: @Qu'est-cet'yont This is what I mean... The code is not placed in #1... Is just inside the environment. The lstset with the options you need for your code language etc (See my 2nd comment)  can replace #1 of lstnewenvironment and you have to remove [1] too. Example: `\lstnewenvironment{code}{\lstset{language={TeX}}}{}` then just `\begin{code}` and `\end{code}` are needed.

Comment: Just remove the `[#1]` and the `\begin{lstlisting}#1` and `\end{lstlisting}` from your code.

Comment: @AlanMunn: it works in this specific useless case, but it doesn't work anymore if I want the environment, say, to take two parameters for two different languages, and to include text in between as well as sections.

Comment: @Qu'est-cet'yont Ok so clarify exactly what you are trying to do, show code based on the duplicate (even if it doesn't quite work), and then we can reopen the question. But remove both of your current code examples, since they *are* solved by the duplicate question.