# Cannot define my own listing environment

Tags: listings, environments

I am trying to define a wrapper for my own listings:

```
\newenvironment{mycode}
{
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
}
{
\end{lstlisting}
}
```

So I can use it:

```
\begin{mycode}
void main();
\end{mycode}
```

When compiling, I get this:

> *** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

---

The full code is here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\newenvironment{mycode}
{
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
}
{
\end{lstlisting}
}

\title{example}
\author{andry.tino }
\date{September 2019}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Hello

\begin{mycode}
void
\end{mycode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Closely related / possible duplicate: [How can I define a custom listing environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78992/134144) To summarize: use `\lstnewenvironment` instead of `\newenvironment`.

Comment: I have voted to close. This is as u pointed out an exact dup. Thanks man