# Make listing a floating image

Tags: graphics, listings, algorithms

I have used the `listings` package for including a program into a LaTeX document. But the program splits into two when a page is finished. I want to make the listing behaved like an image, so that it will not split and the whole program stays on the same page.

Code I used is:

```
\lstinputlisting[caption={Hello},label={pgm1}]{main.c}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please help us to help you and provide a minimal working example of fully compilable code, illustrating your problem, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `float` option to `\lstinputlisting` to make it float:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lstinputlisting[caption={Hello}, float]{main.c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There's also [this question and its answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73231/avoid-page-breaks-in-lstlistings) which have solutions for avoiding page breaks that don't rely on floats.