# Avoid page break in listing

Tags: listings, page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I ensure that a listing is not going to be split?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18492/how-can-i-ensure-that-a-listing-is-not-going-to-be-split)

My listing goes at the bottom of a page and fits good. But the header is separated and moved to another page. Is it possible to keep them together?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) Please add a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/19384) the provides a complete document including package dependencies that reproduces the problem your describe. This will make it easier to provide an answer or help.

Comment: I believe, that this question doesn't require MWE, since I clearly explained what's the problem

Comment: Try putting `float` as the option for your listing.

Comment: @damluar: I think it would be helpful. For example which list you are using.

Comment: @HarishKumar Move it to answers. It helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `float` option to your `lstinputlisting` will make your code to float and floats never break across the pages. Hence the solution will be to use

```
\lstinputlisting[float,caption=My code here]{your file that has code}
```